# convert csharp code to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this csharp code and I want convert to vb.net:

```
var item = (from l in List2 select l).FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null) {...}
```

convert to vb:

```
Dim item = (from l in List2 select l).FirstOrDefault()
If item <> Nothing Then ... End If
```

but get error to **item <> Nothing**

Comment: Took 2 seconds of googling - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx

Comment: Took 1 second of googling http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
If item IsNot Nothing Then
```